# Social media share buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter, google-plus

On stackoverflow, down the left side of my post, there is 3 social media share buttons.

Is there a way to track if the person **successfully shared** with it?

I'm asking, because i track users who "like", "+1" and "tweet" to share pages, but right now I'm using the social buttons provided by the company's like facebook, gplus, twitter and they cause my site to load slow. And it also causes a problem if the user wants to re-share a page sometime down the road, because facebook already marks it as liked, and I'd prefer a way to share pages.

I've tried a few things with my current javascript knowledge and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: have you considered something like AddThis? http://www.addthis.com/

Answer (score 6):

Do the following subscriptions

- **Facebook**: subscribe to the edge.create event (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)
- **Twitter**: put a callback on the `onTweet` parameter (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome#tweetbox)
- **Google+**: put a callback on the `callback` parameter (https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/)

Then in your callback functions, just AJAX whatever you want back to your server for it to store.  :)

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

**Put this in Header**

```
<!-- For Facebook -->
<meta property="og:url" content="https://you-domain.com" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Site Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Site Description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Image you want to set for posts" />
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1" fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<!-- facebook Script End -->


Here are the Series of Button (Facebook, Twitter, Google+, Pinterest, LinkedIn ) put where you want to show share buttons, then Design them from CSS


<!-- For Facebook -->
<a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URL_you_want_to_Share">Facebook</a
<!-- For Twitter -->
<a data-size="large" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=URL_you_want_to_Share">Twitter</a>
<!-- For Google+ -->
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<URL_you_want_to_Share" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'','menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">Google+</a>
<!-- For Pinterest -->
<a  href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=URL_you_want_to_Share" data-pin-custom="true">Pinterest</a>
<!-- For LinkedIn -->
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script><script type="IN/Share" data-url="URL_you_want_to_Share"></script>
```

Comment: For Facebook link `a` tag is missing the end `>`.